# how does scipy.curve_fit determine k and M

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting

I try to do a fit a set of points (x,y) to a function generating x,y value-pairs.
It's really hard to boil this down to a few lines living on their own.
xdata is the polar angle ranging for 0 to 2*pi (1-dimensional)
ydata is the x,y-coordinates. x and y stacked along axis 0. x,y-pairs stacked along axis 1.
elfunxy is a function returning x,y values (stacked along axis 0) for a given phi. And may x,y pairs stacked along axis 1.

```
    xdata = xyrp[:,2]
    ydata = xyrp.T[:2,:] # xyrp ist hstack, curve fit wants (k,M)-shape
    print("xdata.shape: "+str(xdata.shape))
    print("ydata.shape: "+str(ydata.shape))
    print("elfunxy(vector).shape: "+
          str( (elfunxy(xdata, centy,centx,mean*2,mean/2,0.3)).shape ))
    print("elfunxy(value).shape: "+
          str( (elfunxy(1.0, centy,centx,mean*2,mean/2,0.3)).shape ))
    popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(
         elfunxy,xdata, ydata, p0=[centy,centx,mean*2,mean/2,0.3])
```

These lines produce to following output

```
xdata.shape: (67,)
ydata.shape: (2, 67)
elfunxy(vector).shape: (2, 67)
elfunxy(value).shape: (2, 1)
TypeError: Improper input: N=5 must not exceed M=2
```

Why does curve_fit assume M to be 2 and not 67???

Comment: Curve is for 1 dimensional functions using least square. y has to be 1d, and scipy checks `len(y)`, which is 2. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: If you want to fit a multi-dimensional function, you will need to define your own loss function and minimize with one of the general minimization methods.